# Multiple Error Messages C# Script Unity. Need some help (beginning scripter)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I work in unity since 2 days now. I was scripting for a 2d Sprite. When i added the last elements the script didn't work anymore. but i want to make this work. can someone look at the error messages and then to the script to see what is wrong with it.

**Error 1:** *(25,38): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`float' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector2'*

**Error 2:** *(25,38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Physics2D.OverlapBox(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2, float)' has some invalid arguments*

---

**Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    private bool isTouchingGround;


    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        isTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapBox (groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
        movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        if (movement > 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (movement < 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isTouchingGround)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x,jumpSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` instead of `Physics2D.OverlapBox`?

Answer (score 0):

```
isTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
```

If you still wanting to use the OverlapBox, here's the link to the Scripting API for it (I personally got here whenever I'm stuck): [Unity - Scripting API: Physics2D.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html)

Also, I would move the coding for player jumping to the FixedUpdate function instead of the Update function. Seen below is my code from my player controller script from a 2D platformer that I did for a game jam. Hope this helps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkedRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private int extraJumps;


    private void Start()
    {
        extraJumps = 1;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkedRadius, whatIsGround);
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {


        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            extraJumps = 2;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            extraJumps--;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```